# Command Injection bash using Runtime API

Tags: java, security, code-injection, commandinjection

I am trying to test the command injection vulnerability.

I use a servlet that executes the command `ls`, then I try to pass another command in the url to exploit the command injection vulnerability, but when I pass the new command nothing happens. This is my servlet code and the url I use to pass the new command:

```
@WebServlet("/command")
public class CommandInjectionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String comm = "/bin/bash -c ls " + request.getParameter("parameter");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comm);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                response.getWriter().println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.out.println("Error executing command");
        }
    }
    
}
```

and the url that I use `http://localhost:8080/myproject/command?parameter=;ifconfig`

Comment: Try this: `http://localhost:8080/myproject/command?parameter=%3Bifconfig`

Comment: BTW [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) of `exec(String)`: "**Deprecated.**
*This method is error-prone and should not be used, the corresponding method `exec(String[])` or `ProcessBuilder` should be used instead. The command string is broken into tokens using only whitespace characters. For an argument with an embedded space, such as a filename, this can cause problems as the token does not include the full filename.*"

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to get two commands to run in place of one by injecting a semicolon(`;`) into the constructed command string.  The significance of `;` for separating commands is a feature of the shell, so that might work if the command were being run via a shell, analogous to C's [`system()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function.

But [`Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Runtime.html) does not work that way.  Although it's more clear from some of the other overloads, this family of methods is patterned after and works similarly to the [`execve()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) function and its various wrapper functions.  The semicolon has no special significance to them.  The unary `Runtime.exec()` splits the provided string into an array by use of a `StringTokenizer`.  The first element is then taken as the name of the command, and all of the rest as command-line arguments.  That's not susceptible to the mode of command injection you're attempting to perform.

Comment: so how can i resolve this issue

Comment: What do you mean "solve the issue", @midomed?  Is there something unclear about "not susceptible to the mode of command injection you're attempting to perform"? Are you asking how to modify the servlet to *make* it susceptible? The servlet code has some odd characteristics, and probably does not work as intended in the first place, but someone trying to break into a system does not ordinarily start with any control over the system they are trying to crack.